# jOOQ generator does not convert SQL Server datetime2 into LocalDateTime

Tags: jooq

I have the following set in my generator configuration:

```
<generate>
     ...
    <javaTimeTypes>true</javaTimeTypes>  
     ...     
<generate>
```

and a column of type `datetime2`, but it generates a timestamp instead of a LocalDateTime:

```
created_at     datetime2 not null
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. I had the `<generate>` block duplicated which lead to this behavior.